Edit Text in a Model from Sketchfab
I'm completely new to Blender and have spent the past 8 hours trying to figure it out without much success. I've searched extensively online, watched numerous videos, and read articles related to my issue.
I have a model from SketchFab that includes some text I need to modify. Despite my efforts, I'm unable to locate where I can edit this text. I believe I've selected the text, but I can't find any option to make changes. The 'A' icon, indicating editable text, isn't appearing on the right-hand column.
Could someone with a lot of patience please guide me through editing the attached file so I can update the text?
Here's the link to the model:
Thanks for the assist!

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

I'm pretty sure a model downloaded from some random website is not gonna be easily editable or have native text objects you can readily modify. Those are most likely plain meshes shaped as letters you have to remove and replace with actual editable text objects.

Probably all texts from this model are just textures, or at least it looks like it. So editing the texts is an image manipulation more than a 3d work.
